# Going from csv to arrays and use it in a function

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, buddypress, fgetcsv

I've been working with this for so long now I'm ready to succumb and do it manual but because I have invested so many hours into this I really need to accomplish this.

I have a csv-file with information that is required to make a group in [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org)

I am using a function from bp-groups.php (http://pastie.org/1430135) with this script:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include "../../../wp-load.php";

$groups = array();

if (($handle = fopen("groupData.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $group = array('group_id'    => $data[0],
                'creator_id'  => '1',
                'name'        => $data[1], 
                'description' => $data[2], 
                'slug' => groups_check_slug(sanitize_title(esc_attr($data[3]))), 
                'date_created' => gmdate( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ), 
                'status' => 'public', 
                'enable_forum' => '1'
 );
        $groups[] = $group;
    }   
    fclose($handle);
}

foreach ($groups as $group) {
    groups_create_group($group);
} 

print_r($groups);
?>
```

From the print_r I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [group_id] => 2
        [creator_id] => 1
        [name] => GroupName1 
        [description] => Interesting description1 
        [slug] => groupname1 
        [date_created] => 2011-01-05 02:33:54 
        [status] => public
        [enable_forum] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [group_id] => 3 
        [creator_id] => 1
        [name] => GroupName2
        [description] => Interesting description2
        [slug] => groupname2
        [date_created] => 2011-01-05 02:33:54
        [status] => public
        [enable_forum] => 1
    )
)
```

But, the purpose is to create groups from the csv-file, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Anders - How is the csv looks like?

Comment: 2;GroupName1;Interesting description1;groupname1

Comment: 4 columns, hundreds of rows and ; as the delimiter.

Comment: Show a few rows of the csv, or dummy rows formatted in the exact same manner.

Comment: wait wait, does the csv you used to get that print_r output look like this 2;GroupName1;Interesting description1;groupname1 (newline) 3;GroupName2;Interesting description2;groupname2 etc. etc.  Looks like the CSV is being read correctly if so.  The problem is in the adding groups function.  Try checking the include path for wp-load.php, try setting it to the absolute path to the file rather than a relative path like /home/user/public_html/wp_includes/wp-load.php or whatever folder it's in.

Comment: Well, BuddyPress doesn't have nearly as good an online function doc as WordPress does, in fact, can't find one.  I found your post on their forums from a week ago.  I also found that groups_create_group is apparently in a file called bp_groups.php or bpgroups.php or something like that.  You might try looking for and in that file and looking at the groups_create_group function to see what it requires.  If it wasn't loaded, you'd get a big error when trying to use the function.  It might be something it requires in the array that's causing it to drop it without error, or another arg it requires

Comment: Question: Do buddypress groups have parent groups?  If so, it might need a parent value in the array.

Comment: The code function from bp-groups.php are here: http://pastie.org/1430135

Comment: UPDATE: I removed group_id from the script. Reckoned it would generate  it by itself. It now says on the site that I have 790 groups, but the are no where to be found: http://cocacpla.com/test/groups/

Answer (score 0):

PHP's CSV stuff doesn't work that well in my experience, or, well, it only works well with files in a certain format.  CSV files can wind up in different formats depending on what you used to make it, like Excel.  You may have to create a custom parser just using fgets() rather than fgetcsv(), and then explode each line pulled in on the separator character, which is pretty much what fgetcsv is supposed to do.

Also, you might consider something like

```
while(!feof($handle))
{
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";");
    //stuff
}
```

Comment: There's a pretty good reason for that, I forgot the ; at the end of the $data = if you just copied and pasted, so the next thing that it tried to do it wasn't expecting, hence, unexpected Variable.